# Writing a RewriteRule with just one exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, magento-1.7

For a project I need to write a RewriteRule in a .htaccess file but unfortunately I have nearly no experience how to write such rules. What I want to do is rather simple: A complete redirect from one path to another with just one exception. Let me show you my try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/success$
RewriteRule ^.*/wop_de/checkout/onepage.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/wop_de/onestepcheckout/ [R=301,L]
```

What I have thought: If there is no string like "/success" in the URL do a redirect from "/wop_de/checkout/onepage/" to "/wop_de/onestepcheckout/". Well, I guess I was thinking the wrong way as it doesn't work. Could you help me, please?

Also do you know a good tutorial to learn how to write such rules? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^wop_de/checkout/onepage.*$ /wop_de/onestepcheckout/ [R=301,L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.